# From Python to R - time.sleep and break

Tags: python, r

How can I write this time logic with R?

```
 while StatusTest('CSV', Short, username, ItemID, token)['status']!='completed':
        if StatusTest('CSV', Short, username, ItemID, token)['status'] == 'failed':
            print "CSV upload failed"
            break
        time.sleep(5)
        print ("Processing CSV")
```

This is what I've tried:

```
while (accepted != 'completed'){
URL <- paste('http://',short,'.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/',username,'/items/',ItemID,'/status?f=json&token=',token,sep = "")
x <- getURL(URL)
x <- fromJSON(((x)))
accepted<-x$statusMessage
print(accepted)
}
```

but without the `time.sleep` and `break` that I do not really know how to do in R

Comment: Can you give us the code you have tried?

Comment: I edited the question and you can have a look now.thnks

Comment: ok got it solved using Sys.sleep(5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use Sys.sleep(5)

```
while (accepted != 'completed')
{
URL <- paste('http://',short,'.maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/',username,'/items/',ItemID,'/status?f=json&token=',token,sep = "")
x <- getURL(URL)
x <- fromJSON(((x)))
accepted<-x$statusMessage
Sys.sleep(5)
print(accepted)
}
```